# Passing Parameters in a SAS Macro

Tags: parameters, macros, sas

I am writing a macro for a school assignment that will pass the name of an airline to the macro,  I am sure it has something to do with character strings and " and ' that are missing,  But it will not run.  Please tell me what I am doing wrong.

```
%macro select airine=;

proc means data=mytables.airtraffic noprint ;
where bosflights gt 0 and bospassengers gt 0;
by &airline;
var bosflights bospassengers;
output out=mytables.bosflightsairport sum (bosflights bospassengers)=  flights passengers;`
run;
%mend select;
%select airline = Envoy Air;
```

Comment: I had fixed that but still got                       ERROR 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: a name, ;, DESCENDING, NOTSORTED, _ALL_, _CHARACTER_, _CHAR_, 
               _NUMERIC_.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the `()` in your macro definition and call.

```
%macro select(airline=);
...
%mend select;
%select(airline = Envoy Air);
```

Are you passing in the name of the variable or the value of the variable? The way you have written now you are passing in two variable names `ENVOY` and `AIR` that you want to use to group the data in the AIRTRAFFIC dataset.

If you meant the parameter value to be used to subset the data then assuming you have a variable named `AIRLINE` in the dataset then you probably want something like this as the body of your macro.

```
proc means data=mytables.airtraffic noprint ;
  where bosflights gt 0 and bospassengers gt 0;
  where also airline="&airline";
  var bosflights bospassengers;
  output out=mytables.bosflightsairport
         sum(bosflights bospassengers)=  flights passengers
  ;`
run;
```